# How does this array program in C give the result 10?

Tags: c, arrays

I am using Ubuntu 12.04lts with the GCC compiler. This program gives the result 10. Could you anybody please describe why this program gives the result like this?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 void main(void)
 {
     int arr[1] = {10};
     printf("\n%d\n\n", 0[arr]);
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arr[0]` gets internally expanded to `*(arr+0)`. Similarly `0[arr]` gets expanded to `*(0+arr)` which points to the same thing. Hence you see 10.

In general for an array or a pointer `a`, `a[b]` always means `*(a+b)` where `a` is the starting address of the array or pointer and `b` is the offset. Thus, `a[b]` and `b[a]` are equivalent.

Comment: In other words: the very definition of `a[b]` is `*(a+b)`, thus the subscript operator, despite its asymmetrical appearance, is commutative.

Comment: And for a pointer, `p` and integer `i`, `p[i]` and `i[p]` reference the same object too. (Not just arrays, but pointers too.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, of course. I will mention that.

Answer (score 0):

below line means arr is int type array and it has size 1 and it is initialized with 10 ie index 0 has 10

int arr[1] = {10};

then next line printf statement printing the value of arr at index 0.

printf("\n%d\n\n",0[arr]);